# Top Navigation bar hover on selection

Tags: top-link-bar

When you select a menu from the top navigation bar and hover over a selection, how do you change the hover background color.

I've been able to use the NavigationHoverBackground setting in the Color Palette to allow the hover background color on the Quick Launch, but I've been unable to come up with something for the Top Navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for CSS classes of the s4-tn being the default class given to the ASP:MENU

```
.s4-tn{
background-color:#00557B;
padding:0px; margin:0px;
}
/* Global navigation */
.s4-tn li.static > .menu-item{
color:#fff; white-space:nowrap;
border:1px solid transparent;
padding:4px 10px;
line-height:25px;
height:28px;
}
/* Hover */
.s4-tn li.static > a:hover{
background:url("/_layouts/Images/selbg.png") repeat-x left top;
background-color:#0087C1;
color:#000; text-decoration:none;
}
/* Selected */
.s4-toplinks .s4-tn a.selected{
background:url("/_layouts/Images/selbg.png") repeat-x left top;
background-color:#0087C1;
color:#fff; text-decoration:none;
border:1px transparent solid;
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
margin:0px;
}
```